# html footer element is not positioning at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, footer

I want my footer to stick to the bottom of my page, but it is not displayed at the bottom. It goes to aside or to the top close to navigation or, if it`s displayed at the bottom of the page then its background gradient color applies to the upper div element as well.

I have tried the following code:

```css
body::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
}

#footerindex {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

Second code-

#footer {clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;

}
```

```html
 <footer style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e54c8, #8f94fb)">
    <div id="footerindex">
      <a href="terms.html"> Terms and conditions </a> <a href="privacy.html" style="padding-left: 15px;">Privacy Policy</a> 
      <p>&#169; Copyright 2019 - jobg.xyz, All Rights Reserved. </p>
      <p>Website designed and developed by Riven Apwbihls</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox`. For a quick informatic on flexbox click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    Nav
  </nav>
  <main>
    Main
  </main>
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

The `flex: 1` sizes the `main` element to take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

added your `#footerindex` css to `footer`

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}
```

```css
body::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

#footer {clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;

}
```

```html
<footer style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e54c8, #8f94fb)">
    <div id="footerindex">
      <a href="terms.html"> Terms and conditions </a> <a href="privacy.html" style="padding-left: 15px;">Privacy Policy</a> 
      <p>&#169; Copyright 2019 - jobg.xyz, All Rights Reserved. </p>
      <p>Website designed and developed by Riven Apwbihls</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```